# How to use condition in alert.freq

Tags: pine-script

Can you control if timeframe is 15 min then use `alert.freq_once_per_bar_close`, if timeframe is daily then use `alert.freq_once_per_bar` in `alert("message", freq)`?

I tried
`alert("message", timeframe.isminutes? alert.freq_once_per_bar_close: alert.freq_once_per_bar)`
but getting this error:

*"Cannot call 'alert' with argument 'freq'='call 'operator ?:' (simple string)'. An argument of 'simple string' type was used but a 'input string' is expected"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two if blocks to do that.

```
f_tfInMinutes() => 
    _tfInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

is_15_min = f_tfInMinutes() == 15
is_daily = f_tfInMinutes() == 1440

if (is_15_min and alert_condition)
    alert("message", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    
if (is_daily and alert_condition)
    alert("message", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Comment: How do I code for something like
if timeframe = 15, then
   alert("message", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
if timeframe = d, then
   alert("message", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

Comment: Doesn't my code do exactly what you are asking for?